# Roll up line in After Effects?

Tags: after-effects

I'm trying to make the next effect in AE:

[image]

Take the 1st string of guitar and 'broke it', transforming line into a spiral, like this:

[image]

What is the fastest and optimal way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make a spiral like this:

Keyframe it back to a straight line.

If you need more control, you could auto-trace it, and then manually reshape the traced path back to a straight line?